# Validation on front-end with JavaScript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

It's a very unusual thing but...
Intent to change a class of an element when its value matches with a rule by keyup/onchange/input event (all of these already tried).
Have this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cpf').on('input', function () {
        var element = $('#cpf');
        var val = element.val();
        let cpfValue = val.replace(/\D/g, "");
        var result;
        cpfValue.length == 11 ?
            result = validateCpf(cpfValue) :
            result = false;
        console.log('RESULT: ', result);
        result ?
            $('#cpf').addClass('is-valid') :
            $('#cpf').addClass('is-invalid');
    })
    //validateCpf(string) 
    function validateCpf(cpfString) {
        var strStorage = cpfString;
        let total = 0;
        let factor;
        let x;

        function gear(str, onceFirst) {
            if (!onceFirst) {
                var substr = str.substring(0, 9);
                x = validatingDigit(substr);
                console.log('match?: ', x == strStorage.substr(9, 1))
                if (x == strStorage.substr(9, 1)) {
                    var withFirst = str.substring(0, 9) + str.substr(9, 1);
                    gear(withFirst, true);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                x = validatingDigit(str, true);
                console.log('match2? :', x == strStorage.substr(10, 1));
                if (x == strStorage.substr(10, 1)) {
                    console.log('It worked!');
                    return true;
                } else {
                    console.log('no valid');
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function validatingDigit(str, onceFirst) {
                onceFirst ?
                    factor = 11 :
                    factor = 10;
                total = 0;
                for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                    total += parseInt(str.charAt(i)) * factor;
                    factor--;
                }
                var rest = total % 11;
                if (rest == 10) {
                    x = 0;
                } else {
                    x = Math.abs(11 - rest);
                }
                return x;
            }
        }
        gear(cpfString);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<input id="cpf" class="form-control" type="text" name="cpf" />
```

The validating itself is already done (CPF in this case) , but the function, curiosly, returns 'undefined' when it matches, while 'false' when it doesn't, as you can see from the console logs below:

```
8
(índice):96 RESULT:  false
(índice):153 9
(índice):96 RESULT:  false
(índice):153 10
(índice):96 RESULT:  false
(índice):153 11
(índice):114 match?:  true
(índice):124 match2? : true
(índice):126 It worked!
(índice):96 RESULT:  undefined
```

It's a dinamic change.

Any helps will be well come.

Comment: Not sure how this works _at all_, because your `validateCpf` never returns anything - I would have expected this to be `return gear(cpfString);` at the end?

Comment: `cpfValue.length == 11 ? result = validateCpf(cpfValue) : result = false;` - that's quite ugly; this should rather be written as `result = cpfValue.length == 11 ? validateCpf(cpfValue) : false;` Plus, isn't this length check in itself not also part of validation already? So why does it not happen inside of `validateCpf` then?

Comment: I did understand you, but we need to agree this is purely stetical matter... The function returns false (as it should be), but not true when the digits matches. It's a fresh code, intent to have abstractions yet.

Comment: according to that https://youtu.be/-SoHNN6xrqM